# XPath can't find an engine

Tags: java, xpath

I inherited some code that is using XPath for which I am a novice. I have it now so that it loads the document, but when the document.selectPath(queryPath) it always fails with the following error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException:  Trying XBeans path engine... Trying XQRL... Trying delegated path engine... FAILED on //
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path.getCompiledPath(Path.java:173)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path.getCompiledPath(Path.java:130)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._selectPath(Cursor.java:902)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.selectPath(Cursor.java:2634)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:462)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:446)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an XPath engine in your classpath, which one bepends on the XMLBeans version, see
http://wiki.apache.org/xmlbeans/XmlBeansFaq#whatJars

Comment: This was on a project I inherited, so I assumed they had it all set up right. Turns our I had the right xbeans jar in my classpath but the wrong saxon jar, or at least wrong versions of the 2. i redownloaded both and now am all set.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you jor for the post.  I was confused as earlier commands to xml beans were successful.

Without saxon, this still works:

```
MapDocument doc;
...
String cityQuery = "$this//City";
XmlObject[] cities = doc.selectPath(cityQuery);
```

However saxon is required for explicit selection of fields within tags:

```
String aveQuery= "$this//Street[Kind='Avenue']";
XmlObject[] avenues = doc.selectPath(aveQuery); // RuntimeException without saxon on path
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Trying XBeans path engine... Trying XQRL... Trying delegated path engine... FAILED on $this//Street[Kind='Avenue']
```

I hope this might be of use to others that encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

The movement if you have [] in your xpath, it is searching for the external xpath enginer.. you have to download saxonb9-0-0-4j & xmlbeans-xpath-2.4.0.jar and add to the classpath

Answer (score 1):

worked for me:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
>         <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
>         <version>4.0.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>   
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
>         <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
>         <version>10.6</version>
>     </dependency>
>     
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
>         <version>2.1.3</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```